# Blazor not copying generic lists between simple models

Tags: c#, list, blazor-webassembly

This one is driving me slightly mad as it seems impossible. Perhaps I am just missing something obvious. I have been converting an existing Asp.Net Razor web application to Blazor WASM (and generally loving it).

I am simply copying from a model (returned from an API call), to a specific form model for editing (with validation attributes etc). The edit is then shown in a popup, but the problem occurs before then.

The model has an `Id` (string), a `Title` (string), a `Description` (string) which also copies fine and a generic list of a `Property` class called `Properties` which are simple Name/Value string pairs.

As you can see from the screen shot, after the fields are copied, the Properties list on the target object has a zero length.

How is this even possible? I would have suspected a debugger issue, but it fails to render the properties, so it is definitely a zero length list. I have tried both Preview and Release versions of VS 2022 and no change (I tend to use the preview version most of the time, so thought it might be a VS bug).

At first it was a simply assignment, but I made it use `AddRange()` instead and same problem remains. Thoughts? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
public class EditGenericLeafModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Identifier of leaf
    /// </summary>
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Title of node
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 200, ErrorMessage = "Title must be 200 characters or less")]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "";

    /// <summary>
    /// Optional description
    /// </summary>
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 1024, ErrorMessage = "Description must be 1024 characters or less")]
    public string Description { get; set; } = "";

    /// <summary>
    /// List of properties
    /// </summary>
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; } = new ();
}
```

## Update

I changed the `AddRange` to the following even more basic foreach loop and the debugger cannot step into the loop.

```
    if (Model != null)
    {
        form.Id = Model.Id;
        form.Title = Model.Title;
        form.Description = Model.Description;
        foreach (var property in Model.Properties)
        {
            form.Properties.Add(new Property
                {
                    Name = property.Name,
                    Value = property.Value
                });
        }
        //form.Properties.AddRange(Model.Properties);
    }
```

Is it possible it is deserialising as something other than the expected list?

### The JSON transferred looks like this:

```
{
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "ICI-WANTQTY",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Barcode",
            "value": "9772059182020"
        },
        {
            "name": "ICI-ORDER",
            "value": "8"
        }
    ],
    "id": "T000002FT2",
    "title": "Lego Star Wars Issue 85 (Darth Maul polybag minifigure)",
    "description": ""
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mre] somewhere? For example at github? Also have you tried full rebuild + cleaning browser cache (and deleting bin and obj folders )

Comment: @GuruStron Have cleaned and deleted bin and obj. Problem remains. It will take a while to build a stand alone repro of this. Will try that later if nobody has any clue.

Comment: Lots of clues, and none about `AddRange`. The debugger you see is actually the *browser's* debugger, showing the results of WebAssembly execution. .NET does a lot of magic to make things work like .NET's debugger, but there are always limits. Is `Model` an actual component parameter? `OnParametersSetAsync` is called when a component's parameters change from the outside. Perhaps the contents aren't what you expect?

Comment: You can use bUnit to test components in isolation and check what's going on. The code you posted is essentially mapping code. You can extract that into a separate method and test it independently

Comment: [Parameter]
    public GenericLeaf Model { get; set; }

Comment: Found it. I had 2 identically shaped models. As one was derived from the other, so it allowed the deserialise, but there were effectively 2 identically named properties called `Properties`. Compiler should have caught that one.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the heads-up about debugging effectively being via Javascript. It explains some of the "Javascriptiness" of the models I am now debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the cause was rather interesting and worth knowing about:

The compiler did not catch that I was basically **deserialising to a base class when a derived class referenced elsewhere had an identical property**.

It effectively masked the real property from the debugger.

I have deleted the derived class as it was no longer needed and all is good.

Comment: What you describe is a C# issue that probably generated a compiler warning. There's probably a warning saying that `B.Prop` is hiding `A.Prop`.